# Using a Variable in a Command Cooldown Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to get a variable to be my cooldown in a command. Is this possible?
For example, something like:

```
timevariable = 60
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,timevariable, commands.BucketType.user)
```

Anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`commands.cooldown()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.cooldown) with a variable. Here is an example of it:

```py
timevariable = 10
@commands.cooldown(1, timevariable, commands.BucketType.user)
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('You can use this command every 10 seconds.')
```

1 determines how many times the command should be used to trigger the cooldown.

[`BucketType.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.discord.ext.commands.BucketType.user) means every user can use it for every 10 seconds. You can change it to (for example) [`BucketType.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.discord.ext.commands.BucketType.guild).

In this case, if someone uses that command, no one in that guild can use this command in 10 seconds.